# vulkan.hpp unique handles for extensions

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors, vulkan

I am trying to create a unique handle for  a  `vk::DebugUtilsMessengerEXT` object.

To this effect I have loaded `VkCreateDebugUtilsMessenger()` into a function pointer and then call it to create the plain C structure, which I then turn into a unique vulkan.hpp object through

`vk::UniqueDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(messenger, instance);`

This is where the issue begins. This kind of object calls the destructor implicitely, that is to say it will attempt to call `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` when the variable leaves the scope. However this function cannot be loaded into a pointer with the same name.

i.e defining a function pointer as `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT`

And then setting it as

```
vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) instance.getProcAddr(
        "vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
```

Will result in a compilation error as I am redefining the symbol.

```
error: ‘void (* vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)(VkInstance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT, VkAllocationCallbacks)’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
```

However not defining it causes a linker error, as the linker cannot find the symbol to link against for the destruction of the unique handle.

```
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Debug/main.o: in function `vk::DispatchLoaderStatic::vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance_T*, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT_T*, VkAllocationCallbacks const*) const':
/home/kronos/Desktop/Vulkan/Generated/../libraries/vulkansdk-linux/1.1.97.0/x86_64/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp:1770: undefined reference to `vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT'
```

How do I get around this? How can i expose that symbol to allow for compilation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the answer upwards, it could be better like the following code:

```
using unique_debug_utils_messenger_ext = UniqueHandle<DebugUtilsMessengerEXT, DispatchLoaderDynamic>;
...
UniqueInstance instance_{nullptr};
UniqueDevice device_;
unique_debug_utils_messenger_ext debug_messenger_;
DebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debug_messenger_create_info;
DispatchLoaderDynamic dispatch_loader_dynamic_;
...
dispatch_loader_dynamic_ = {*instance_, *device_};
debug_messenger_ = instance_->createDebugUtilsMessengerEXTUnique(
            debug_messenger_create_info,
            nullptr,
            dispatch_loader_dynamic_);
```

The code enables you to still use the smart pointer feature. More details are provided in DispatchLoaderDynamic implementation in vulkan.hpp.

Comment: And ALSO, do not forget to release them before destroying the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Defining a function with the same name as the requested function and calling the pointer inside of it allows for compilation and linking.

In essence:

```
void (*vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessenger)(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator);
void vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator)
{
    vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessenger(instance, debugMessenger, pAllocator);
}
```

Creates the symbols needed for linikng and compilation and:

```
vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessenger =
        (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(
            instance, "vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
```

Will properly initialize the pointer.